# How to zoom to fit in WP7 Bing Maps control using LocationCollection?

Tags: windows-phone-7, location, zooming, bing-maps

How can I zoom the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map control to the correct zoom level on Windows Phone 7?

I have a LocationCollection of GeoCoordinates and I calculated the Center myself, but now how do I calculate the correct zoom level to fit the LocationCollection?

P.S. Is there an out of the box method to calculate the center of GeoCoordinates so I don't have to calculate it myself?

EDIT:
I've found another fine solution: http://4mkmobile.com/2010/09/quick-tip-position-a-map-based-on-a-collection-of-pushpins/

`map.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(points));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following code to calculate the `LocationRect` that bounds a set of points, and then pass the `LocationRect` to the `SetView()` method on the map control:

```
var bounds = new LocationRect(
    points.Max((p) => p.Latitude),
    points.Min((p) => p.Longitude),
    points.Min((p) => p.Latitude),
    points.Max((p) => p.Longitude));
map.SetView(bounds);
```

The map control handles animating from the current position to the new location.

NOTE: You'll need a `using` statement for `System.Linq` to get the `Min` and `Max` methods.

Comment: Yep, this is how I did it. Works nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer, however I've found another fine solution: map.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(points)); // http://4mkmobile.com/2010/09/quick-tip-position-a-map-based-on-a-collection-of-pushpins/

Comment: Thanks. Glad you found a solution. I'll have to make a mental note that LocationRect helps out more than I thought :)

Comment: This is a nice solution, but note that if your points are around the 180 longitude line, this code will not work. You will get a rectangle in the width of the entire world...

Comment: It's called LocationRectangle in Windows Phone 8 if anyone were a bit confused like I was :)

Answer (score 1):

Derek has already given the answer so you should accept his, I offer an alternative code for cases where there many points.  This approach only iterates the points collection once instead 4 times however it isn't as asthetically pleasing.

```
 double north, west, south, west;

 north = south = points[0].Latitude;
 west = east = points[0].Longitude;

 foreach (var p in points.Skip(1))
 {
     if (north < p.Latitude) north = p.Latitude;
     if (west > p.Longitude) west = p.Longitude;
     if (south > p.Latitude) south = p.Latitude;
     if (east < p.Longitude) east = p.Longitude
 }
 map.SetView(new LocationRect(north, west, south, east));
```

Comment: +1 .. and I wouldn't call this a premature optimization; I'd call the accepted answer a premature degradation :-)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the other answers I use `SetView` with a `LocationRect`.

However I found that it always produces to low zoom level, since only integer values was used. If for instance the perfect zoom level would be 5.5, you would get 5.0. To get a proper fit I calculate a new zoom level from `TargetZoomLevel`and `TargetBoundingRectangle`:

```
viewRect = LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(coordinates);
map.SetView(viewRect);
double scale = map.TargetBoundingRectangle.Height/viewRect.Height;
map.ZoomLevel = map.TargetZoomLevel + Math.Log(scale, 2);
```

This example sets the zoom level to fit `viewRect`'s height on the screen.